# XCode IBOutlet UIView added to ViewControllers .h -- UIViews type not recognized

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I have added the view of my view controller as a property to the view controllers backing .h file myViewController.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView* view;
```

When writing view.window inside one of myViewController.m methods, Xcode marks that line as an error with "property 'window' not found on object of type view". It fails to build. Note I originally chose the views backing class view.h as the type. I already clean ed the project.

Specifically I get the error here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
displayLink = [view.window.screen displayLinkWithTarget:(self) selector:@selector(drawFrame)];
}
```

How can I resolve this? I like to access the view controllers views window inside one of the view controllers methods.

Comment: Don't add an outlet named "view" because it will conflict with the standard outlet on all `UIViewController`s named `view`. Try using a different name.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I actually use a different name. I removed the prefixes I chose for clarity's sake.

Comment: I solved it. I named the outlet with the same name as I named the views backing class. This caused the error. Naming the outlet different from the class solves it. Thank you for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the @synthesize statement?

Don't name an outlet "view", that causes confusion with UIViewController that has a view property.

Currently Apple defaults to making iOS IBOutlets weak. This has changed since the early iOS SDKs. IBOutlets that are weak will generally work if they are retained by a super view or controller.

Comment: the @synthesize statement is in the view controllers .m. UIView.h is imported by view.h and view.h is imported in the view controllers .h. The outlet is weak as per the default. Being weak worked for other projects. I compared to other projects (which didn't access the view itself though) and couldn't find a difference.

Comment: On iOS IBOutlets are strong, on OSX they are weak.

Comment: understood. tried. didn't solve it. The "Your First iOS App" guide from Apple uses ARC and weak properties. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @LarsHansen That is interesting! Perhaps Apple is changing their philosophy on retaining.

Comment: You and @JasonCoco basically gave the right hint: a naming conflict. Although I didn't grasp it from your answer until now (I read "outlet view" instead of "outlet 'view'") and the "solving" is a comment to my original post, I chose this answer as the preferred because I can't do so for the original answer. However this question has a solution thus some marking is appropriate. Thank you.